# How to center text in a UITableViewCell when accessory is UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

Tags: xcode, ios5, uitableview

I'm trying to keep text centred in a UITableViewCell when I have the accessoryView set to UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark. I'm also using a storyboard with this class.

Here's a screenshot of what I don't want.

How do I stop the text from being indented to the left?

[image]

My willDisplayCell method..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == [self cellToCheckmark]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not Being Checked");
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    if (cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing == YES) {
        cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;
    }
}
```

CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Google";
                break;

            case 1:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Bing";
                break;

            case 2:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Yahoo!";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    if (indexPath.row == [self cellToCheckmark]) {
        NSLog(@"Being Checked");
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not Being Checked");
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    if (cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing == YES) {
        cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;
    }   
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iOS 8+ solution:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = ...;
    if (/* your condition */) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 40, 0, 10);
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is there any documentation about why is 40?

Comment: @SoniaCasas No, only empirical observations. I didn't find any Apple's constant or runtime value for that.

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 things you need to do:

First, you need to make sure you set the table style to Default: `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. All other styles use a `detailTextLabel` in one way or another and you won't be able to set the textLabel's alignment property.

```
[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
```

Then you can set the alignment of your cell's textLabel:

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Then setting the accessory to checkmark based on whatever your data requires.

```
cell.accessoryType = ( myDataMatches ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone );
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I am using a storyboard with this class. How does that change the answer?

Comment: Does not matter whether you are using a StoryBoard or not. These properties apply only to a `UITableView`

Comment: I've updated my question. Does it matter that I've used static cells instead of prototypes?

Comment: It should work if you put that code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This is how I center text in my tables and I have one that uses a checkmark as well. See my screenshot in my answer.

Comment: Include the code from your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you may have some other stuff going on there.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a much simpler answer (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34136898/386738)). In short, you are centering the label in the cell's content view. Instead, center it in the cell itself, then it won't move.

Tried it out, it works on iOS 11.2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These solutions work for default cells. If you have your own custom cell, the easiest way to do it is make the label have constraints both to the left margin and the right margin, then create an outlet for your left margin constraint, and set its constant in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
    cell.accessoryType = isChosen ? .checkmark : .none
    cell.leftMarginConstraint.constant = isChosen ? 40 : 0
```

This way, the right margin which is added for your accessoryType is then added to the left as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if the problem is solve

```
if (/* your condition */) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.indentationLevel = 4;
    }else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.indentationLevel = 0;
    }
```