# UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark and AutoLayout constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have custom `UITableViewCell` and manage selection of my cells. When the cell is selected and the checkmark is presented, the cell `Content View` width shrinks and my labels with trailing constraints move to the left. How can I effectively avoid the content move?

I did not want to set the constraints to leading as I have flexible tableview width and they are right aligned. When I want to update label's constraints in code via its `IBOutlets` I went into trouble as I return multiple subclasses of `UITableViewCell` in `cellForRow:` and I got unrecognized selector error in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` when trying to set constraints in code. Any elegant solution? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behavior is by design.

The simplest way to get the behavior you want is to set an empty accessory view on every cell which will move all the content to the left the same distance as the checkmark.

Comment: Don't forget that the accessoryView takes priority over the accessoryType. The accessoryType won't show up if you have a non-nil accessoryView.

Comment: When running this on iPhone Xs simulator (12.4), an empty UIView causes the accessory view to be off by a few pixels, causing a slight gap when showing/hiding the checkmark. With this solution the only way to make this work properly, would be to use the same width as the checkmark button, which is not a very flexible solution.

Comment: Challenge with this approach is figuring out what distance is the "same distance as the checkmark" if using Apple's built in `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`

Comment: George, an empty accessory view will inset the same amount as the checkmark. At least it did in 2014.

Answer (score 31):

I had a similar (actually, the exact) problem, where the checkmark would push everything to the left.

**- EDIT:**

A few hours after my original answer, I realized it's a really simple issue.

This push to the left is a constraint pushing the **contentView** of the cell. So?

Connect the constraint from the item on the right (like the **i** button), **to the cell itself**, not its contentView.

[image: Constraint to cell view]

---

---

*- Original answer (**the actual answer is on top, this is for the record**):*

I just realized there's a very simple solution. I had a button that was pushed left when checkmark was on and I had to keep a constraint to keep it in place (so that 'uncheck' won't move the button to the right). It was hard-coded 'width' from the right and overall just bad practice. Never mind that I could not 'get' that checkmark 'width' to do this dynamically.

Solution?

Hold a constraint from the left.

That's it. I have a label too, so in my case: Constraint from the button left to the label (so they won't overlap) and from the button-left to left content-view. Basically, whatever moves on the right does not really 'reaches' the left side (rather have everything 'sitting' on the right).

[image: Cell with constraints to left]

Comment: Both good answers, and much simpler than the accepted solution!

Comment: This does not work Xcode 9, Swift 4, iOS 9.3. Auto Layout complains, and breaks the constraints. Which, really, it should do.  The basic problem is that's an Apple design flaw: UITableViewCell sucks, just like UITableView. It's a decade old, and ready for the scrap heap.

Comment: Recently used this setting again, it's still works here (Xcode 9.2). If there are constraints issues, could be that there are previous constraints that conflicts with it.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting the checkmark in there all the time, and just playing with the alpha / transparency?

```
    if checked
    {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        cell.tintColor = cell.tintColor.withAlphaComponent(1)
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        cell.tintColor = cell.tintColor.withAlphaComponent(0)
    }
```

Comment: Good idea. But won't work if you're using appearance proxies. For example, `UIButton.appereance().tintColor = .red` will cause `cell.tintColor` to be ignored.

Comment: …but if you're not using appearance proxies (), this works great! 