# Defining Constraints for UITableView with UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

Tags: uitableview, swift, constraints

I have a UITableView containing four cells. The first two have `UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator` while the other two have `UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None`. As a result, my constraints which are made with the right hand superview are different for the cells which have a disclosure indicator and those that don't.

I read here: [UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark and AutoLayout constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933094/uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark-and-autolayout-constraints)
that I should set an empty accessory view for the remaining cells, is this a built in type of accessory? I can't find it, what is mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a build type. The answer in the link you're refering is saying that you should set a non-nil view to the `accessoryView` property of the `UITableViewCell` instance. Eg. `yourCell.accessoryView = someBlankView`.

Comment: I had actually figured this out quite some time ago but thank you for answering.

Comment: You´re welcome. Maybe the answer can be useful to people with similar question.