# Prevent cell check mark inside UITableViewCell shifting labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have a table view set up in a view controller. When the user selects a row, a check mark appears. When the deselect the user deselects the row the check mark disappears.

The cell is a custom cell with two labels inside of it. When a checkmark appears it shifts both labels left. How can I prevent this?

I am using autolayout/constraints and it is not an option not to use them.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried setting the checkmark height and width to a fixed value  and then using only the hidden property of this view?

Comment: @MP23 No I haven't edited the check mark at all. Could you please put an answer with a code example showing this method? :-)

Comment: hm, I am assuming that you have in your custom cell views as following: two UILabel and some other view e.g UIImageView with checkmark image am I right? It would be easier if you could post your piece of code that is not working as expected and screenshot or description of autolayouts you have used.

Comment: This question's response answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22953563/2273902