# Attaching views to UITableViewCell's right edge with changing accessory

Tags: ios, uikit

When adding right-aligned views to a `UITableCellView`, the view will shift when changing between different accessory types.

How can I avoid that?

[image: sample]

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to just let it move. That's the way iOS is designed to work. But there are plenty of [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22953563/2518285) if you want to mess about.

Answer (score 1):

A pattern I found useful is to constraint the "right-aligned" view's trailing edge to the UITableViewCell's trailing edge + 40, rather than to the Content View's trailing edge.

This way you accommodate even the larger accessory types, whose sizes are unfortunately not uniform (e.g. 31px for Disclosure Indicator vs. 39px for Checkmark vs. 0px for None).

This helps when you're trying to implement e.g. temporarily switching into a "checkmarking" mode.

[image]