# Xcode: AccessoryType.checkmark pushes other views to the left

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, accessorytype

Xcode 10, Swift 5, iOS 12

My app contains 3 `ViewControllers`:

1. Login
2. TableView
3. Detailed info about data of single row in TableView

If you edit and save the data in ViewController 3 and use the "back" button (through a `NavigationController`) to go back to ViewController 2, a checkmark is added to the corresponding row in the TableView.

The problem is that this checkmark pushes everything else to the left, even though I left some space for it:

[image]

Setup:

- Horizontal `StackView` with 2 subviews with 1 label each
- The StackView is set to "Fill"
- The second subview is half as wide as the first one
- 10 pts leading on the left and 40pts trailing on the right (also already tested with 100pts but no change)

I already tried adding an `AccessoryType.none` to each row (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22953563/2016165)) when I create them - like this:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.setLabels("Label1","Label2")
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none //This doesn't work either

    return cell
}
```

but it doesn't get added (same thing with the other types).

How do I fix this? Is it possible to set the checkmark "behind" everything else while still using an `AccessoryType`?

Comment: The answer you linked to says to use an ***empty accessory view*** ... that is not the same as setting `AccessoryType.none`.

Comment: @DonMag Oh. How do I do that? There's no layout element for that in the library. It's weird though that adding a checkmark during the setup doesn't seem to work. I noticed that it is possible to add an accessory directly in the "Attributes inspector" of the cell, then change its color via "Tint" to the background color and later just change the tint to e.g. red to make the checkmark visible. But I'm not too fond of this solution because it's semi-hardcoded to the background color.

Comment: I'm also experiencing something weird: If row 0 gets a checkmark, row 11 does too (same thing with 1&12, 2&13,...). My func only gets called once for sure (I added a "print" in the beginning) and the IndexPath only says something like `[0,2]` (row 2).

Comment: Okay, it depends on the size of the emulator: It only happens to a row that's not visible, so with the iPhone SE emulator it's row 11 that is marked in addition to row 0 (0-9 are visible, 10 barely. With iPhone 7 it's row 16 (0-11 are visible, 12 only half) and with iPhone Xs it doesn't happen at all. What's even weirder: The marking moves around when I scroll up and down (always down by one row)!

Comment: Cells are re-used, so you cannot just "set the checkmark". You have to set it to either `.checkmark` or `.none` *every time*.

Comment: @DonMag `Every time`? You mean every time I use the "back" button to go back to my TableView? The problem occurs when I scroll up or down, not when I switch view. I remember the `IndexPath` of the cell that was last selected, then set the checkmark in `viewWillAppear` (of VC2).

Comment: In `cellForRowAt` you ***must*** set `cell.accessoryType = .none` OR `cell.accessoryType = .checkmark`. Otherwise when the cell is re-used it will retain the last value. By the way, `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = ...` is absolutely wrong. Just set the property on `cell`.

Comment: Okay, adding the checkmark in `cellForRowAt` worked this time (not sure what changed this time). I only keep a reference to the `IndexPath` I get through `didSelectRowAt`, I never actually get my hands on the cell directly unless I call `tableView.cellForRow`. Should I add all the cells to an array through `cellForRowAt` instead? Edit: Just tried keeping a reference to every cell but now multiple cells get the checkmark again. I'll better move this to a new question (going to post a link here).

Answer (score 1):

Inside your UITableViewCell you created to handle the cell add the following function. This function tests if this current cell has an accessoryType set and if not then it makes the cell 40pts smaller, thus making the cells with and without accessory the same size for the auto layout.

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    get {
        return super.frame
    }
    set (newFrame) {
        var frame = newFrame
        if self.accessoryType == .none {
            frame.size.width -= 40
        }
        super.frame = frame
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of approaches to this, but I think the best approach is to add an image view to your custom cell and use your own checkmark image.

[image]

Then when you set the labels' text in `cellForRowAt`, instead of setting `cell.accessoryType = .checkmark` where needed, set the image of the image view to your own checkmark image (or, set the image view `.alpha` to `0` (not shown) or `1` (shown)):

[image]

Of course, you'd use your own *much better* checkmark image than the one I grabbed for this example :)

**Edit:**

If you want to use a tint color, you can set your image to a "template" image. Something like this in your cell init:

```
    checkImageView.image = checkImageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    checkImageView.tintColor = .red
```

---

**Edit 2:**

If you don't want to use a custom image, you can constrain your stack view's trailing edge to the **Cell** instead of to the cell's **Content View**:

[image]

40-pts looks about right, but you'd want to confirm that, and you'd want to double-check that the spacing is the same on different devices (retina vs. non-retina, etc).

Also, the proper way to set the accessory is to set it on the cell in `cellForRowAt`. Assuming (based on your comments) that you are keeping a reference to the selected row - let's say it's

```
var currentSelectedIndexPath: IndexPath!
```

You want to do something similar to this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

    cell.leftLabel.text = "Left \(indexPath.row)"
    cell.rightLabel.text = "Right \(indexPath.row)"

    cell.accessoryType = (indexPath == currentSelectedIndexPath) ? .checkmark : .none

    return cell

}
```

---

**Edit 3:**

You need to do some more reading on table views, cells, selections, data tracking, etc...

But, here is a complete example for you.

First, the Storyboard. Create a new single-view project. Right-click on the Storyboard and select

`Open As -> Source Code`

Delete what's there, and paste in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="KbA-Q0-LNC">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14460.20"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Selected Row Table View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="DAq-F3-sy8">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController id="qt8-QK-wnn" customClass="SelectedRowTableViewController" customModule="XC10SWScratch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" id="2Gh-42-LWt">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <prototypes>
                            <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="MyCustomCell" rowHeight="56" id="r8I-XK-VkK" customClass="MyCustomCell" customModule="XC10SWScratch" customModuleProvider="target">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="56"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="r8I-XK-VkK" id="MvA-eu-x6f">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="55.5"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" spacing="10" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mQ2-DJ-vUS">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="10" y="0.0" width="325" height="55.5"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bfe-Sh-FxV">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="210" height="55.5"/>
                                                    <subviews>
                                                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 1" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Hhj-4f-3ME">
                                                            <rect key="frame" x="10" y="10" width="190" height="35.5"/>
                                                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </subviews>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstItem="Hhj-4f-3ME" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="bfe-Sh-FxV" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="BXa-Av-XMu"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Hhj-4f-3ME" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="ND3-SS-NJN"/>
                                                        <constraint firstItem="Hhj-4f-3ME" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="bfe-Sh-FxV" secondAttribute="leading" constant="10" id="fhX-ir-pnY"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Hhj-4f-3ME" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="jCn-Ib-SDq"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                </view>
                                                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ydx-kR-Ui2">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="220" y="0.0" width="105" height="55.5"/>
                                                    <subviews>
                                                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 2" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vaR-rB-U1a">
                                                            <rect key="frame" x="10" y="10" width="85" height="35.5"/>
                                                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </subviews>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstItem="vaR-rB-U1a" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ydx-kR-Ui2" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="5LB-SK-csH"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="vaR-rB-U1a" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="ghm-bd-7PC"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="vaR-rB-U1a" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="rIn-3p-Lpj"/>
                                                        <constraint firstItem="vaR-rB-U1a" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ydx-kR-Ui2" secondAttribute="leading" constant="10" id="z1q-yz-bd6"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                </view>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="ydx-kR-Ui2" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="bfe-Sh-FxV" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.5" id="4h1-AF-V9L"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </stackView>
                                    </subviews>
                                    <constraints>
                                        <constraint firstItem="mQ2-DJ-vUS" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="MvA-eu-x6f" secondAttribute="top" id="HNe-Ks-vip"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="mQ2-DJ-vUS" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="MvA-eu-x6f" secondAttribute="leading" constant="10" id="RCj-FT-gww"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="mQ2-DJ-vUS" secondAttribute="bottom" id="azO-kX-4jB"/>
                                    </constraints>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="groupTableViewBackgroundColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="mQ2-DJ-vUS" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="40" id="UCo-0w-3ki"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <connections>
                                    <outlet property="leftLabel" destination="Hhj-4f-3ME" id="WQS-bJ-KeJ"/>
                                    <outlet property="rightLabel" destination="vaR-rB-U1a" id="RXC-UG-g5P"/>
                                </connections>
                            </tableViewCell>
                        </prototypes>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="qt8-QK-wnn" id="aMA-fV-5cb"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="qt8-QK-wnn" id="S0n-bN-MLJ"/>
                        </connections>
                    </tableView>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="kxZ-av-xIt"/>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="qxa-2p-Cxd" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1556" y="830.73463268365822"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="d0B-12-bYa">
            <objects>
                <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="KbA-Q0-LNC" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="jcB-K3-ueL">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="375" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="qt8-QK-wnn" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="YsO-wj-izb"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="5gD-zl-juz" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="616.79999999999995" y="830.73463268365822"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

You can then Right-click on the Storyboard and select

`Open As -> Interface Builder - Storyboard`

to view the layout.

Next, replace the contents of the default `ViewController.swift` with this code:

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var leftLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var rightLabel: UILabel!

}

class SelectedRowTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

        cell.leftLabel.text = "Left \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.rightLabel.text = "Right \(indexPath.row)"

        cell.accessoryType = (tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow == indexPath) ? .checkmark : .none

        return cell

    }

}
```

You should then be able to run the app. Inspect the constraints on the custom cell, and review the code (very, very basic) to see how the checkmark is set on the selected row (and removed on the unselected row), and how it is set correctly when scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. If I can't find a way to do it properly with an `AccessoryType` (I like that you can easily change the color with them), I'm going go try it with an image. Do you happen to know how to do it with `AccessoryType` though (and fix the problem I described in my last comment)?

Comment: See my edit for how to tint the custom checkmark image.

Comment: @Neph - see my "Edit 2"

Comment: 40pts should be more than enough, I even tried 100 but everything still got pushed off to the side. The constraint is set for the StackView, not the ContentView and it doesn't even let me add constraints for that or the cell itself (everything's grayed out). Is setting the AccessoryType in `cellForRowAt` the same as picking the checkmark in the dropdown menu of the cell's "Attributes Inspector"? How do I change the cell's tint color afterwards, so the checkmark appears next to the right cell? I now even tried keeping a reference to every cell but the colored checkmark is still moving around.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I changed the "trailing" constraint connection from the StackView to the cell element and with 40pts (still have to test other emulators) there's enough space that nothing's pushed to the left. I'm still dealing with the checkmark moving though and eventually it even vanishes completely.

Comment: Sorry, triple-post. I don't want to remove the checkmark again. I'm not using the TableView as some kind of check list but it's a list of items that are marked off once they've been edited/the changes saved. Once evey list item is marked, you can do other stuff with it (still have to implement that). So no matter how often I tap on a specific row (which loads View Controller 3 anyway), scroll up or down the list (or even check out the information in VC3 for a different row), I don't want any checkmark to move or vanish. Apart from `didSelectRowAt`/`didDeselectRowAt` your code looks like mine.

Comment: Then you need to add a BOOL element to your datasource, and set it to true or false, based on the "checked" state. Change `cellForRowAt` to `cell.accessoryType = (myData[indexPath.row].mySelectedState == true) ? .checkmark : .none`

Comment: So basically I have to remember which rows have been marked off and mark them again every time `cellForRowAt` is called? I though that's only called automatically once when the TableView is set up.

Comment: Ah, got it (I think, still needs more testing) - thanks!: `cell.accessoryType = (rowsSaved[indexPath.row]==true) ? .checkmark : .none` - I also had to add `myTableView.reloadData()` to `viewWillAppear`, otherwise the checkmark doesn't appear until I scroll up/down, so the row is invisible for a second. Or is there a better way of reloading it?

Comment: As I said in my edits... *You need to do some more reading on table views, cells, selections, data tracking, etc...* These are pretty basic tableview / data management tasks. We're way beyond the scope your original question.

Comment: I know, I'm still pretty new to Swift and still have a lot of stuff to look into. ;) Thanks for your help! I have to do a lot more testing to check if everything's now working the way I want it to but I won't be able to do this today.

Comment: Using 40pts for the `accessoryType` has been fine since last year but unfortunately this changed after updating Xcode to 11.5 and the device/emulator to iOS 13.5: With 40pts it now looks like the checkmark is aligned to the left instead of being in the center (tested with a real SE and an SE2 emulator). Even 50pts isn't enough to make it look centered, while 55pts is too much. 52pts looks about right (tested with `.checkmark` and `.detailButton`) but is it possible to get the exact measurements for that or, even better, make it only use 40pts again (52pts looks too big)?