# Handle changed size of AccessoryType in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios13, accessorytype

About a year ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55746309/2016165) about how to place an `AccessoryType.checkmark` on the very right of specific cells in a `UITableView`. This was solved by constraining the trailing space of the `UIStackView` (contains the two labels, see image below) to the `UITableViewCell` (= grandparent) instead of the `ContentView` (= parent) with a hardcoded `40pts`.

With this the checkmark was then centered in its own little space on the right side "within" the cell but not affecting the widths of the labels or even pushing the `ContentView` to the left (which would have been the default behavior).

After updating Xcode to 11.5 and installing iOS 13.5 on my testing device (iPhone SE) yesterday, it looked like this:

[image]

To center the checkmark again I had to change the trailing space to `52pts` (simply guessed as [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1744561/2016165), as 50pts is too little and 55pts too much):

[image]

Unfortunately this takes away quite a bit of space from `Label 2` and also looks weird because of all the unnecessary free space around the checkmark.

I read that Apple overhauled their icons with iOS 13 and it looks like they also increased the size of the `AccessoryType`s, which would explain why they now need more space to be centered.

**Question:** How do I make the checkmark use less space again? Either by decreasing the size again or taking away some of the space on the sides (is there an option 3?) but while still using `AccessoryType`.

Comment: The default behavior for a cell is to decrease the width of the content view when an accessory view is shown. When you don't want that, among the options are: use your own accessory view that is blank or shows a checkmark; use a custom view instead of accessoryType. Using the previous approach did run the risk that Apple would change the layout. (Although, it is a little odd that the accessory image is now left-aligned in the allotted space).

Comment: In the question I linked I had the problem you mentioned: The cell+its labels were pushed to the left by the accessoryType (there's an image). You gave me the tip to constrain the `UIStackView` (contains the labels) with the grandparent, not the parent, which makes it look like in the images above: The labels always look the same and the checkmark is "on top" but doesn't affect the width. The checkmark is "left-aligned" in the 1st image because the grey part is only 40pts. This worked with the old checkmark but apparently the new one is bigger and needs 52pts to be centered, which is too big.

Comment: Yes... I understand the issue. Apple does change UI elements from version to version. For the layout you want, I would strongly recommend implementing your own checkmark view, or some other visual indicator of the selected row.

Comment: I'm pretty bad at creating images and my own checkmark (it has to be a checkmark) probably wouldn't look great, so I'd rather use the default one (plus, it automatically sets the color that way). The question is if it's possible to keep that symbol but either make it smaller or take away some of the space on the sides. Currently the old version of my app looks good on iOS 12 devices but not on iOS 13 ones and the new version of my app looks good on iOS 13 but not on iOS 12. I'm looking for something that's kind of universal and looks good on both versions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not unusual for Apple to change aspects of the UI. For example, the "system" font has changed a couple times between iOS versions. In this case, it appears the position of the checkmark accessory image has been left-aligned in the accessory view space (in iOS 13).

While you often ***want*** your UI elements to change when Apple makes the change (a good example is `UISegmentedControl`) so your app's interface matches the OS, sometimes you don't.

In this case, to get the most consistent appearance across iOS versions, it's wise to use completely custom UI implementations.

Here is an example of using a PDF for the checkmark image (so we can retain vector scaling), and setting it's `Render As` property to `Template Image` so it will conform to tint coloring.

First, here's how it looks in Storyboard:

[image]

We'll use a custom cell class and **override** its `accessoryType` property:

```
class CustomCheckedCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var leftLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var rightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var myAccessoryView: UIImageView!

    override var accessoryType: UITableViewCell.AccessoryType {
        set {
            myAccessoryView.alpha = newValue == .none ? 0.0 : 1.0
        }
        get {
            return .none
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // we use contrasting colors to design the cell in Storyboard
        //  so set all backgrounds to clear at run-time
        guard let lView = leftLabel.superview, let rView = rightLabel.superview else {
            return
        }
        [lView, rView, leftLabel, rightLabel].forEach {
            $0?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
}
```

We can now use the default `cell.accessoryType = .checkmark` or `cell.accessoryType = .none` to show / hide the checkmark image *without* affecting the layout of the cell.

Here's an example controller class:

```
class CustomCheckedCellTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // we can set the table view's tint color here (tint's our custom checkMark accessory)
        tableView.tintColor = .red
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCheckedCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCheckedCell

        cCell.leftLabel.text = "Left \(indexPath.row)"
        cCell.rightLabel.text = "Right \(indexPath.row)"

        cCell.accessoryType = (tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow == indexPath) ? .checkmark : .none

        return cCell

    }

}
```

and the output looks like this:

[image]

Here is the Storyboard source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="KbA-Q0-LNC">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Custom Checked Cell Table View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="DAq-F3-sy8">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController id="qt8-QK-wnn" customClass="CustomCheckedCellTableViewController" customModule="iOS9SDK" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" keyboardDismissMode="onDrag" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" id="2Gh-42-LWt">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <prototypes>
                            <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="CustomCheckedCell" rowHeight="56" id="r8I-XK-VkK" customClass="CustomCheckedCell" customModule="iOS9SDK" customModuleProvider="target">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="56"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="r8I-XK-VkK" id="MvA-eu-x6f">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="56"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alignment="center" spacing="10" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mQ2-DJ-vUS">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="16" y="0.0" width="311" height="56"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bfe-Sh-FxV" userLabel="LView">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="200.5" height="56"/>
                                                    <subviews>
                                                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 1" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Hhj-4f-3ME">
                                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="10" width="200.5" height="36"/>
                                                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </subviews>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.97680455450000003" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstItem="Hhj-4f-3ME" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="bfe-Sh-FxV" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="BXa-Av-XMu"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Hhj-4f-3ME" secondAttribute="trailing" id="ND3-SS-NJN"/>
                                                        <constraint firstItem="Hhj-4f-3ME" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="bfe-Sh-FxV" secondAttribute="leading" id="fhX-ir-pnY"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Hhj-4f-3ME" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="jCn-Ib-SDq"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                </view>
                                                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ydx-kR-Ui2" userLabel="RView">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="210.5" y="0.0" width="100.5" height="56"/>
                                                    <subviews>
                                                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 2" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vaR-rB-U1a">
                                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="10" width="100.5" height="36"/>
                                                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </subviews>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.97680455450000003" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstItem="vaR-rB-U1a" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ydx-kR-Ui2" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="5LB-SK-csH"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="vaR-rB-U1a" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="ghm-bd-7PC"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="vaR-rB-U1a" secondAttribute="trailing" id="rIn-3p-Lpj"/>
                                                        <constraint firstItem="vaR-rB-U1a" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ydx-kR-Ui2" secondAttribute="leading" id="z1q-yz-bd6"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                </view>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="ydx-kR-Ui2" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="bfe-Sh-FxV" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.5" id="4h1-AF-V9L"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </stackView>
                                        <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="myCheckmark" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="s8x-tM-09v">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="339" y="17" width="20" height="20"/>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="20" id="4UJ-FQ-7yW"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="s8x-tM-09v" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="bVw-JC-DCh"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                            <preferredSymbolConfiguration key="preferredSymbolConfiguration" weight="semibold"/>
                                        </imageView>
                                    </subviews>
                                    <constraints>
                                        <constraint firstItem="s8x-tM-09v" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="mQ2-DJ-vUS" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="12" id="G9K-If-FTj"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="mQ2-DJ-vUS" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="MvA-eu-x6f" secondAttribute="top" id="HNe-Ks-vip"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="s8x-tM-09v" secondAttribute="trailing" id="M5d-Rz-1R2"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="mQ2-DJ-vUS" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="MvA-eu-x6f" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="RCj-FT-gww"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="mQ2-DJ-vUS" secondAttribute="bottom" id="azO-kX-4jB"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="s8x-tM-09v" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="mQ2-DJ-vUS" secondAttribute="centerY" constant="-1" id="qpV-6I-bLK"/>
                                    </constraints>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                                <connections>
                                    <outlet property="leftLabel" destination="Hhj-4f-3ME" id="WQS-bJ-KeJ"/>
                                    <outlet property="myAccessoryView" destination="s8x-tM-09v" id="hUo-ed-Kyz"/>
                                    <outlet property="rightLabel" destination="vaR-rB-U1a" id="RXC-UG-g5P"/>
                                </connections>
                            </tableViewCell>
                        </prototypes>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="qt8-QK-wnn" id="aMA-fV-5cb"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="qt8-QK-wnn" id="S0n-bN-MLJ"/>
                        </connections>
                    </tableView>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="kxZ-av-xIt"/>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="qxa-2p-Cxd" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1556" y="830.73463268365822"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="d0B-12-bYa">
            <objects>
                <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="KbA-Q0-LNC" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="jcB-K3-ueL">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="qt8-QK-wnn" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="rwh-Te-ifH"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="5gD-zl-juz" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="616.79999999999995" y="830.73463268365822"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="myCheckmark" width="50" height="50"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

and the PDF file for our custom checkmark image (I just stuck it in an unrelated GitHub repo, since we can't pst pdf files here):

https://github.com/DonMag/PDFImagePanZoom/blob/master/myCheckmark.pdf

When you add the pdf file to your asset catalog, don't forget to set Render As, Preserve Vector Data and Single Scale:

[image]